# Python Beautifulsoup Duplicate entry's

Tags: python, image, beautifulsoup, duplicates, screen-scraping

This scrapes images from 4chans photography board. The problem is that it scrapes the same image twice. I can't figure out why I am getting duplicate photo's, if anyone could help me that would be awesome.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import urllib2
import os


def get_soup(url,header):
  return BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url, headers=header)), 'lxml')

image_type = "image_name"
url = "http://boards.4chan.org/p/"
url = url.strip('\'"')
print url
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} 
r = requests.get(url)
html_content = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'lxml')
anchors = soup.findAll('a')
links = [a['href'] for a in anchors if a.has_attr('href')]
images = []
def get_anchors(links):
for a in anchors:
    links.append(a['href'])
return links

raw_links = get_anchors(links)

for element in raw_links:
if ".jpg" in str(element) or '.png' in str(element) or '.gif' in str(element):
    print element  
    raw_img = urllib2.urlopen("http:" + element).read()
    DIR="C:\\Users\\deez\\Desktop\\test\\"
    cntr = len([i for i in os.listdir(DIR) if image_type in i]) + 1
    print cntr
    f = open(DIR + image_type + "_"+ str(cntr)+".jpg", 'wb')
    f.write(raw_img)
    f.close()
```

Comment: 4chan has two links to the same image in each post, one link in blue before the image and one link around the image itself.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. How could I get rid of the other one?

Comment: You could add all the links into a list, remove duplicates, and only then download all links from the list.

Comment: Could someone point me in the right direction with some code? I'm pretty confused as how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pull every anchor, use the class name to get certain links:

```
import  requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://boards.4chan.org/p/").content)

imgs = [a["href"] for a in soup.select("div.fileText a")]

print(imgs)
```

The reason you have dupes is there are at least two divs that have the same link for each image:

[image]